# Limit media player fullscreen to the bounds of my application

Tags: c#, .net

So a lot, if not most of all Media Players have a "fullscreen" mode. My application has a WebBrowser control and also an embedded Windows Media Player control. Now the problem here is that the fullscreen mode is literal. It actually covers my whole screen.

Is it possible to somehow modify the behavior of my application so that all "fullscreen" modes only stretches to the bounds of my application. Basically only "fullsceens" inside my application?

Any hints or suggestions are welcome!
Only idea that I could come up with it somehow fool windows thinking that my application is a monitor. But maybe that's taking it too far?

Answer (score 0):

No way, sir.
"Full screen" is "full screen" and it is managed by OS to cover all the screen.
If you need to adapt the video size based on parameter you can't work on full screen.

Comment: That's a bummer. Thanks for the answer.